# What plaster compounds should be used when plastering an unheated building?

Tags: drywall, plaster

Remodeling an old school that was built in 1902 that had plaster stripes on inside walls. they want it to look original.  Will it work to put 1/2inch OSB on the wall and then a layer of plaster on the OSB? tape the joints of course. This building will not be heated and is located along the Ohio River where it is very damp. What plaster compound should i use and will this work, or any other suggestions

Comment: What is the planned use of the building?  Why will it be unheated?

Comment: It is being restored for Little Pioneer Village in Cannelton, In. Were they restored old cabins and other old buildings as original as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put plaster on OSB. Put plaster on plasterboard aka blueboard. OSB is very moisture sensitive. Your plan will eventually result in rotten, swelled OSB with plaster falling off of it, especially if the building won't be heated.